# Jupyter lab : Server Connection Error: Failed to fetch

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc, jupyter-lab

I have created a Google Dataproc cluster with the optional components Anaconda and Jupyter. When I try to open the Jupyter Lab or Jupyter UI from cluster web interface, some times I am getting the following errors that pop-up in the UI which do not allow me to create or use any notebooks.

1. Server Connection Error: Failed to fetch
2. Server Connection Error: 500. That’s an error. That’s all we know

I am using Dataproc image version 1.3-debian9 with python2.7 which is is created using the following gcloud cmd:

```sh
REGION=us-central1
CLUSTER=spark-jupyter-1-3

gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER} \
 --region=${REGION} \
 --image-version=1.3 \
 --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
 --enable-component-gateway
```

Any advise how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It could be caused by component gateway or knox error, you can try SSHing into the master node, then run `sudo systemctl restart knox` and `sudo systemctl restart google-dataproc-component-gateway`, to see if it recovers.

Comment: [1] Your link is to a HTTP 401 error message which makes no sense in the context of that sentence.[2] Do not link to text or images. Instead, embed them within your question.

Comment: Do you still see this error if you try to use version 1.4 or 1.5? 1.5 is also now in general availability. Is there a reason you are using 1.3?

Comment: all of our python scripts are using 2.7 ,due to that i can't use >1.3 version